# Which site to ask about downloading a package using apt-get?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I'm not sure where to ask this question. My questions have been removed from Stack Overflow (which would be my first assumption as to where this question should go) before because they are not strictly about programming.

I am trying to download the text-based browser elinks by following the video *[Elinks installation tutorial (Ubuntu/Mint)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2gzn8QAlWA)* , but I could not because the terminal gave me the error "sudo: apt-get: command not found". What should I do to fix this so that I can download elinks.

Here is a picture of my terminal in case it is helpful:

[image: My terminal]

Comment: In addition to Unix & Linux, it should be acceptable on Super User.  Disclaimer: I am not active on SU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it is a Unix/Linux terminal, [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) could be the appropriate site. Or even [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) since you seem to be using a Ubuntu distro.

You could ask on Unix & Linux SE's meta if this question would be allowed there, but I think you don't have to worry, since it already has an [apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt) tag there. It might already have an answer too. (Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49071/126677) one?)